# Trocar imagem da Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou criando um app pelo Android Studio e escolhi **Navigation Drawer Activity** como a tela do sistema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria de saber como faço para alterar o fundo verde e colocar uma imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que seja no bloco abaixo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
```

Nessa linha:

```
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
```

Não tenho certeza, mas se for, como faço para alterar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui alterar. Para isso, copiei a imagem que queria colocar e colei dentro da pasta **drawable** do Android Studio, depois alterei a linha:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg16"
```

E funcionou!